# How can I get an input box to appear on the same line as other content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have some text on a row, followed by an input box on the same row.

However, the input box is always going to the next row, even though there's enough space for it on same row as the text. I looked in the documentation, and there is only advice there to do what I want for forms (i.e class form-horizontal).

However, I just want some text (`<p>` tag) and then an input box.

See simple JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dz089gac/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Hi</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="hi">
    </div>
</diV>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <span>Hi</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="hi">
    </div>
</diV>
```

Use `span` instead of `p` tag as `p` creates block of element and place a new line after the tag close.

Comment: Or a `label` tag. You can then also associate it with the input control.

Comment: @adrianbanks yes label tag also can be used. as you want to use you can.

Answer (score 1):

A paragraph (p) is a block-level element. That means it takes up the entire "row" it is on.

You should strongly consider using a label (label) instead, which is more semantically correct in this context and, as such, provides a few benefits:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="my_input_element">Hi</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="hi" id="my_input_element">
    </div>
</diV>
```

Clicking on the label will set the focus on the corresponding input element, and screenreaders (and other devices) recognize that the label is associated with the input, rather than a block of unrelated text. This is *exactly* what a label is INTENDED to be used for.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s62evwmz/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `p` is a block element and the next element will start on a new line.

If you can not change the element type or move the input into the `p` tag then you can use css to make the `p` element inline.

```
.row p{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dz089gac/3/

Answer (score 0):

Put inside the paragraph.

```
<p>Hi <input type="text" placeholder="hi"></p>
```

But that is much more better, if you are using `labels` instead of `p`

```
<label>Hi <input type="text" placeholder="hi"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but i have put the input type into the `</p>` tag.

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dz089gac/9/)

Answer (score 0):

just put the input inside the `<p></p>`

e.g.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Hi <input type="text" placeholder="hi"></p>
    </div>
</diV>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz089gac/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display property of `<P>` tag to the inline-block value i.e. `display=inline-block` and if required you can give some margin for the Box this will add space between them.
ie .

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p style="display:inline-block;">Hi</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="hi" >
    </div>
</diV>
```

Demo Link : http://jsfiddle.net/dz089gac/10/